# Laravel folder permission for not-yet made cache folders

Tags: linux, laravel, debian

I'm having an issue with directory permissions with Laravel when it comes to caching. Whenever it tries to upload a cache file to `/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/cache/data/` it tells me that `file_put_contents` has no permissions.

To fix this I always do something like `chmod -R 755 /var/www/laravel/storage/framework/cache/` but the problem here is that when it creates a new directory inside `cache` it does not inherit these chmod settings, thus giving me permission denied error again.

How can this be fixed permanently?

Edit:
Been thinking about letting it run as a cronjob regularly, but I'm not so sure that's a good way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `chmod` command with `-R`:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#installation

Comment: Sloppy mistake, I forgot mentioning thats what I do. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Yes, but after some time it starts throwing me the permission denied error again.

Comment: because the files get created with specific permissions, nothing is inherited from a folder